Get data from Visualizations of Power BI to Jupyter Notebook
I am trying to create DQ reports for my Power BI report. I am using python to connect to my Power BI report. For this i am using this code. I am getting error on this:
from powerbiclient import Report, models
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication
import pandas as pd

device_auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()

report_id = 'abc'
workspace_id = 'def'

report = Report(workspace_id=workspace_id, report_id=report_id, auth=device_auth)

pages = report.get_pages()

Exception: Power BI report is not embedded
Can someone please help how do i achieve this?

Initially I got the same error:

To resolve the error, include report._embedded=True in the code and modify it like below:
from powerbiclient import Report, models
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication
import pandas as pd

device_auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()

group_id = 'abc'
report_id = 'def'
report = Report(group_id=group_id, report_id=report_id, auth=device_auth)

report._embedded=True

report.get_pages()



Reference:
python - Exception: Power BI report is not embedded - Stack Overflow by Kotana Sai
